# How to sort array with unique elements by datetime (Python)

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.x, multidimensional-array, sorting

So my issue is that I exported an excel file as a csv file. I've imported the file into Python and added it to a matrix which looks like:

```
A = [[1, '13/04/2015 12:22:45'],
     [2, '13/04/2015 12:22:46'],
     [3, '12/04/2015 12:30:00']]
```

I want to sort this by date and time. I have found several solutions that sort datetimes using the built in `sorted()` function, but none of the examples have additional array columns with other values.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you share some code for your sorting for us to see what you have tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you probably want to be able to construct datetime objects from the strings that you have for comparison purposes:

```
import datetime
def make_datetime(lst):
    date_str = lst[1]
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%s')
```

Now you can use this as the key to your sort function:

```
sorted_A = sorted(A, key=make_datetime)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I didn't realise that I had to convert to a datetime object first. My original code was sorting based on the string like zachgates7's answer below. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by the second element (your datetime) using

```
A.sort(key=lambda i: i[1])
```

This is assuming that you want to sort by the string, rather than the actual date. Otherwise, take a look at **mgilson**'s answer.

Comment: Hmmm... I think this doesn't quite work:  `[[1, '13/04/2015 00:00:00'], [2, '12/05/2015 00:00:00']]` -- You can't compare as strings with the current date format OP is using.

Comment: I took back my upvote as, for example, `"12/04/2000" > "11/05/2000"` is `True`